# How should I write batch update method by spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

here is a method I need to update a mysql table by a DTO list, I update them one by one, here is my code:

```
@Override  
  @Transactional  
  public void updateCustomCategory(List<ItemDto> itemDtoList) {  
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(itemDtoList)) {  
      for (ItemDto itemDto : itemDtoList) {  
        Long l1CustomCategoryId = itemDto.getL1CustomCatId();  
        Long l2CustomCategoyId = itemDto.getL2CustomCatId();  
        StringBuilder query =
                new StringBuilder(
                        "update ItemDto item set item.l1CustomCategoryId = :l1CustomCategoryId and item.l2CustomCategoryId = :l2CustomCategoyId where itemId = :itemId");  
        Query q = this.em.createQuery(query.toString());  
        q.setParameter("l1CustomCategoryId", l1CustomCategoryId);  
        q.setParameter("l2CustomCategoyId", l2CustomCategoyId);  
        q.setParameter("itemId", itemDto.getItemId());  
        q.executeUpdate();  
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to modify it into a batch update to keep the performance good if the data size is huge, How should I do?

Comment: why don't you persist via entities? create an updated entity for every loop and persist them at once

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update see this link

Comment: because using every entity for every loop will also have a performance issue just same as my currently codes, I wanna do the bulk update

Comment: You should really use Spring Data. Create a findAllByItemIdIn(List<Item> items) to return the list of items. Then modify them in memory locally on the serivce and use the saveAll from spring data to save back to the database. This way you're only executing only two DB queries per batch.